# I wonder why there is a LimitedBox here in Flutter Container when child is null, what's the point about maxWidth == 0.0?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

I wonder why there is a LimitedBox here in Flutter Container when child is null, what's the point about maxWidth == 0.0?

```
if (child == null && (constraints == null || !constraints.isTight)) {
  current = LimitedBox(
    maxWidth: 0.0,
    maxHeight: 0.0,
    child: ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand()),
  );
}
```

is equal to

```
if (child == null && (constraints == null || !constraints.isTight)) {
  current = ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand());
}
```

Comment: because if you remove that [LimitedBox](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart#L388) and use just `child: Container()` returned `current` would be `null`

Comment: why not just use `ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand())` instead, and what's the meaning of `maxWidth: 0.0` due to `A box that limits its size only when it's unconstrained.`

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @pskink, i finally found the reason. it explained well  [flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Column(children: [Container1(color: Colors.red)]));
  }
}

class Container1 extends Container {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget current = child;

    if (child == null && (constraints == null || !constraints.isTight)) {
      current = ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand());
    }

    return current;
  }

  Container1({Color color}) : super(color: color);
}
```

demo failed with reason

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderFlex#a3fb7 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
The constraints that applied to the RenderConstrainedBox were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=390.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(390.0, Infinity)
```

`LimitedBox(maxWidth: 0.0, maxHeight: 0.0)` make container width or height to 0 when Container(no child) as a child of Row\Column\UnconstrainedBox\OverflowBox which has no tight width or height constraint. otherwise it width or height will overflowed.

without it, you can never use code like this:

```
Column(children: [(boolValue) ? Widget1() : Container()])
```